# Thingsboard owner change doesnt make any change on devices group

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

The problem is when i try to move a device from a customer/device group into my main tenat device group with owner change it doesnt move. Actualy it moves device but it still shows under customer/devicegroup  and when i try to move it again , it gives error: Entity already belongs this owner

i was expecting to move device to main device group with owner=tenant it says it moved but still shows under customer device group

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.